# Asset management tool for a JS-only application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for an asset manager (equivalent to [these Rails tools](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Asset_Management)) for a pure JavaScript/HTML application.

The features I would like are as follows:

- Keep separate JS and CSS files during development, concatenate them into one minified file for production.
- Append a unique GET parameter after each production deployment, to prevent browser caching (`index.min.js?q=123515111`).

There may be other useful things I haven't thought of, but that's the minimum I'd like.

I'm only working with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I'm not currently using Rails, or any other server- or client-side MVC framework. Is there a standard tool for managing resources when you aren't using a framework?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use Apache Ant for anything. You wouldn't include the files with a query string appended though, but you can use a build ID to include in the file names (which would be better anyway).

Comment: Search for javascript loader and dependency management, for example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqln2akPWiMIdERkY3J2OXdOUVJDTkNSQ2ZsV3hoWVE#gid=2

Comment: @amadeus that's awesome, thanks! looks like require.js is the way to go for me. if you submit an answer i will accept it.